# c# generic list subtype operations not working

Tags: c#, generics, subtyping

I have a subtyped list:

```
public class LDBList<T> : List<T> 
    where T : LDBRootClass { ...
```

I need to concat them

```
LDBList<TSHeaderItem> catted = tsh1.Concat2(tsh2);
```

(and TSHeaderItem is indeed a subtype of LDBRootClass)

I get

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LDB.TSHeaderItem>' to
> 'LDB.LDBList<LDB.TSHeaderItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are
> you missing a cast?)

The offered cast just pushes the error from compile time to runtime.

Now I can see what's happening, ok, but I don't know how to fix it. So

1. what do I do here specifically, and
2. More importantly I obviously don't know enough about c# generics so to get the underlying knowledge about how to solve ***these class of problems***, where do I start reading?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that its *almost* never desirable to inherit from `List<T>`, you could create a copy constructor:

```
public class LDBList<T> : List<T> where T : LDBRootClass
{
    public LDBList(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }
}
```

Which would allow you to do this:

```
var catted = new LDBList<TSHeaderItem>(tsh1.Concat2(tsh2));
```

As for your second question, this really has nothing to do with generics but relates to the type system in general.

`tsh1.Concat2(tsh2)` returns `IEnumerable<TSHeaderItem>`, not `LDBList<TSHeaderItem>`, so you need to do something to convert the `IEnumerable<TSHeaderItem>` into a `LDBList<TSHeaderItem>`.

Although `LDBList<TSHeaderItem>` implements `IEnumerable<TSHeaderItem>`, not all `IEnumerable<TSHeaderItem>`s are `LDBList<TSHeaderItem>`s, in fact in this case the runtime type of `tsh1.Concat2(tsh2)` would be `ConcatIterator<TSHeaderItem>`.

Comment: Thanks, will try! Why is it undesirable to inherit from List? Happy to encapsulate rather than inherit if you recommend it. Also I understand what's going on but "...so you need to do something to convert the..." is the key - where do I start reading to be less n00b on the subject; be able to fix these probs?

Comment: The merits of inheriting from `List<T>` have been discussed many times; here is one such discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt.

Comment: As for converting the types, every scenario has it's own specific solution, so there isn't really a general area of reading. Fortunately the authors of `List<T>` realised that creating a list from an `IEnumerable<T>` would be a common requirement and they provided a "copy constructor" that performs the conversion.

Comment: the 'why not inherit' is mostly a discussion of is-a vs has-a. My use of list is in principle an is-a so is inherited, and if I discover that's a mistake I can flip to encapsulation very easily.